# Gitlab commits have the wrong ID

Tags: macos, git, gitlab

Developers committing on our internal network, from the company computers (we're using iMacs) have their commits display as developerX@macY.local, where I'd expect them to display as developerX@company.com.

Since I expected the commit to be linked to the commuter by way of the SSH key inserted in their account on the GitLab server, I'm perplexed at the situation that uses their local identity, e.g. the ID they have during the commit.

I expect telling Git to use their email as id globally will fix the issue, but I'm wondering if there is a Gitlab file/setting where I could add additional information, so that all developerX adresses display as their email, rather than setting up their ID in Git manually on each computer they might connect from, and have 'broken' commit IDs anytime one of them forgets.

Answer (score 3):

Did your users run the following in the terminal? This usually what gets displayed when they commit.

```
git config --global user.name "USERNAME"
git config --global user.email "EMAILADDRESS"
```

Comment: This is the solution. The transport mode's authentication (SSH, HTTPS, file share) is just that: authentication. By the time it comes into play, a commit is already registered in the local repository. These commits cannot be modified afterwards without changing the commit hash.

Comment: @DanielB Good addition

Comment: I said in my question that fixing it globally would work, but that it doesn't solve the problem I have, as per my last paragraph, it just does a hot fix at a given point in time. This is not the solution to the question I asked, it is a solution to the question "how do I get the correct username for my users to display". Thanks, though.

Comment: You can also rewrite history (which as you stated will change the commit hash) to edit the programmer's id after the fact, but the point of my question is precisely to avoid these shenanigans in a project where you may have a lot of programmer turnover and teaching people to use git properly will regularly end up in these issues showing up. That's the point, imho, of using high level tools such as Gitlab instead of standard Git.